# I Need assistance with paper minecraft plugin in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: kotlin, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

When making my minecraft paper 1.19.3 plugin in IntelliJ Idea, I get an error like this:

> Unresolved reference: setExecutor

I have tried googling it, and I can't find anything about it.

Btw all the code is in kotlin and not java.

I cant figure out what the problem is I have tested to fix it many times but it dosent work.

This is all my code.

IN Test.kt

```
package me.albindev.test

import me.albindev.test.commands.JumpCommand
import me.albindev.test.listeners.PlayerJumpListener
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin


class Test : JavaPlugin() {
    override fun onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        logger.info("Hello World!")

        getCommand("jump")?.setExecutor(JumpCommand())

        registerListeners()
        registerCommands()
    }


    private fun registerListeners() {
        server.pluginManager.registerEvents(PlayerJumpListener(), this)

        logger.info("registered listeners")
    }

    private fun registerCommands() {
        getCommand("jump"!!.setExecutor(JumpCommand()))
    }

    override fun onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }
}
```

_
**In JumpCommand.kt**

```
package me.albindev.test.commands

import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.TextColor
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.TextDecoration
import org.bukkit.command.Command
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender
import org.bukkit.entity.Player
import org.bukkit.util.Vector

class JumpCommand : CommandExecutor {

override fun onCommand(sender: CommandSender, command: Command, 
label: String, args: Array<out String>?): Boolean {
    if (sender is Player) {
        if (sender.isOp) {
            sender.sendMessage(Component.text("Command Was Successful!").color(TextColor.color(0,255,0)).decorate(TextDecoration.BOLD))
             sender.velocity = sender.velocity.add(Vector(0.0, 10.0, 0.0))
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(Component.text("YOU ARE NOT OP!").color(TextColor.color(255, 0, 0)).decorate(TextDecoration.BOLD))
            }
        }


        return false

    }
}
In PlayerJumpListener.kt
package me.albindev.test.listeners

import com.destroystokyo.paper.event.player.PlayerJumpEvent
import net.kyori.adventure.text.Component
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.TextColor
import net.kyori.adventure.text.format.TextDecoration
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler
import org.bukkit.event.Listener

class PlayerJumpListener : Listener {

    @EventHandler
    fun playerJumpEvent(event: PlayerJumpEvent) {
        val player = event.player

        player.sendMessage(Component.text("You Jumped!").color(TextColor.color(0, 255, 0)).decorate(TextDecoration.BOLD))
    }
}
```

**In plugin.yml**

```
name: test
version: '${project.version}'
main: me.albindev.test.Test
api-version: 1.19
authors: [Albin (Alosi)]
description: test
commands:
   jump:
       description: Fly into the air
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have "!!" in the code line? As I see it that's a syntax error.

```
getCommand("jump")!!.setExecutor(JumpCommand())
```

That wont work, the proper syntax should be like this:

```
getCommand("jump").setExecutor(new JumpCommand())
```

This can also be applied in the "registerCommands()" function. Also, does your command class implement "CommandExecutor"?

Comment: yes it does you can chack my last post

Comment: They are different languages, i guess you are using java but he is using kotlin